# Use a Nop Service outside of a controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I'm writing a custom validation attribute for validating zip\postal codes. For it to work I absolutely need to know the selected country. But it turns out to be surprisingly difficult to do.

In most view models nop passes the country using its id, which means I need to decipher it. The way to do it would be to use `CountryService` since it can translate the id to country name, but the problem is how do I actually do that.

If I were to create a new `CountryService` object I would have to also create and pass a number of dependencies (CacheService object etc.) and it sounds like the wrong way of achieving the result. So how do I actually use a Nop Service outside a controller (in my case inside a custom Validation Attribute)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to *create* the object but get an instance from the service locator.

Something like this:

```
var countryService= EngineContext.Current.Resolve<ICountryService>();
```

You can check any attribute in nopCommerce like `WwwRequirementAttribute` and check how it uses the locator pattern.